# JQuery: Modify SVG element dimensions

Tags: jquery, html, svg

I have an svg tag embedded in HTML. The following code does nothing:

```
var svg = $('svg');
svg.attr({
    width: "300px", 
    height: "300px"
});
```

In fact, I haven't been able to modify its size in CSS either. The only way I've managed is by setting width and height attributes in the html itself:

```
<svg 
    width="300px"
    height="300px"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" 
    xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" 
    xmlns:ev="http://www.w3.org/2001/xml-events"
></svg>
```

How should I be changing the size of the SVG area? Do I need a JQuery SVG plugin for it? (Please provide example code).

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest posting an example of what you're doing on e.g [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net).

Anyway, you don't really need jQuery to do this. [Here's an example](http://xn--dahlstrm-t4a.net/svg/html/inline-transition-size.html) that uses CSS transitions to change the width and height properties of the inline svg fragment that is hovered by the mouse.

A guess is that if the changes don't affect your svg fragment, then you have some CSS that is overriding those changes.